# Why is my code always giving out 0 as a result?

Tags: python, binary

I was making some excrecises to convert a given 2's complement input into a decimal number, but I'm constantly getting 0 as the result with the code I wrote.

```
def convert_decimal():
    sign_len = int(input("Please enter the number of bits for your value: "))
    binary_value = str(input("Please enter a binary value in 2's complement to be converted into decimal: "))
    bin_reversed = binary_value[::-1]
    result = 0
    if binary_value[0] == 0:
        for bit in range(len(binary_value)):
            result = result + int(bin_reversed[bit]) * (2 ** bit)

    elif binary_value[0] == 1:
        minimum = -1 * 2 ** (sign_len - 1)
        for bit in range(len(binary_value)):
            result = minimum + int(bin_reversed[bit]) * (2 ** bit)

    print(result)
    return(result)


convert_decimal()
```

But when I exclude the part inside the if statement and run it as it is it works, but since in 2's complement there are negative numbers too I need to use the initial element of the binary number to decide if it is negative or positive. Can someone please help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not updating `minimum` each time through the loop. So the final value of `result` just comes from the last iteration added to the original `minimum`.

Comment: But what is the reason it's not working on the first statements part? Shouldn't work there since minimum does not have any value there? Also how can I fix the situation with that?

Comment: In the `if` block you're accumulating changes in `result`. In the `else` block you're not accumulating anything.

Comment: simply use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"` and it can help you to see where you have mistake.